# How to prevent flickering due to jquery addition of img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript snippet

```
var render_applist_entry = function (info) {
    var html = '<div class="row">';
    html += '<img src="static/images/generic_appicon_128.png" class="col-sm-2 va" />';
    html += '<div class="col-sm-7 va"><h4>'+info.image.name+'</h4></div>';
    html += '<div class="col-sm-2 va">';
    html += '<button id="'+info.mapping_id+'" name="action" value="start" class="start-button btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none"></i> Start</button>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    return html;
};
```

I add it using `$("#applist").html(htmlcode)`, but unfortunately in Chrome I obtain an unpleasant flicker between the time the div is rendered and the time the image is loaded (the image is larger, so the entries are reformatted)

I tried adding a display: none and keep it hidden to reveal it in a single shot, but in practice it doesn't work.

Keep into account that I don't know a priori the size of the image, nor I can load it using javascript.

I did not observe the effect in Firefox (but I doubt it matters).

Comment: You are triggering a browser [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow).

Comment: `Keep into account that I don't know a priori the size of the image` oops my bad!

Comment: What exactly do **you** want to do to fix the flicker? either way there's going to be a jump, so you have to decide whether you want to preallocate and show a loading icon, or do nothing and show it all at once, or something else. and... in all of those cases you'll need to do some tracking on whether or not the image is done loading.

Comment: @KevinB I want to be able to show the fragment without the additional change in div size due to the image appearing. Like the table is added and appears with the images already loaded and properly formatted.

Comment: Then what you'll want to do is delay showing anything until the image is done loading.

Comment: @KevinB Yes but it's a catch-22. The image load is triggered only when that content is added to the DOM, from what I can see.

Comment: well, no, look up image preloading. or, here it is in a nutshell: `var img = new Image(); img.onload = addDivToDom; img.src = 'theimage.jpg';` you shouldn't need to add it to the dom for the loading to occur.

Comment: @KevinB: This one looks interesting. I suspect that if I preload it with the css background it should work: https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Answer (score -1):

Create a document fragment that is never part of the main DOM tree. I provided the documentation from MDN. It does not have anything to do with Firefox and is applicable to Chrome as well.

From this [MDN doc for Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment#Example):

> The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append elements
>   to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the
>   DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all
>   its children.

```
//Create a document fragment
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();    
var divElem = document.createElement("div") ;
//Add the div element to the document fragment
docFrag.appendChild(divElem);
//Create class attribute
var classAttr = document.createAttribute("class");
classAttr.value = "row";
//Set the class attribute for the div element
divElem.setAttributeNode(classAttr);
//Repeat this for the img element 
var imgElem =  document.createElement("img");
var srcAttr = document.createAttribute("src");
srcAttr.value = "static/images/generic_appicon_128.png";
divElem.appendChild(imgElem);
//****************************************************
//Repeat the element creation for all your html tags 
//****************************************************
//Finally add your document fragment to your html. It will only trigger one reflow and 
$("#applist")[0].appendChild(docFrag);
```

A note on the same page on document fragments:

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main
>   DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow
>   (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using
>   document fragments often results in better performance.

Comment: It is absurd the downvoter could not explain them self. narcissist.

Comment: well, no, i downvoted your answer because it's not going to remove the flicker. in other words, it is incorrect and/or wrong. not useful.

Comment: Expecting discussion. I am expecting the time spent in answering a question is to get a topic cleared.